# Deserialization of renamed typed DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, dataset

Is there a way to rename a typed DataSet but still allow it to deserialize data serialized using the previous name/schema settings?

Example:

Having the original serialized DataSet stored in ASP.NET session state in a database named `DSAdmin`, after renaming it to `AdminDataSet` and logging in again an exception will be thrown since it can not deserialize to the new type from the old type stored in the session DB:

```
[SerializationException: Unable to load type DAL.DataSets.DSAdmin required for deserialization.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups() +14219464
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +244
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +447
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +28
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader) +1224
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert() +108
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check) +338
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name) +27
   MasterPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) in x:\iis\wwwroot\Admin\MasterPage.master.cs:60
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +186
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +291
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2098
```

**Update**

SchemaSerializationMode property of the dataset being set to `IncludeSchema`.

Comment: Not sure, but possibly it could help to make the new type derive from the old type. Yes, it isn't a straight rename, but should help in maintaining backwards compatibility with the old name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to recover an object serialized via "BinaryFormatter" after changing class names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701481/is-it-possible-to-recover-an-object-serialized-via-binaryformatter-after-chang)  That question answers how to deal with a renamed type.  Not sure about your changed "schema settings" however, so if that answer is incomplete, can you give an example of how your schema changed?

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490113/c-sharp-binaryformatter-deserialize-with-the-object-in-another-namespace

Comment: @dbc: Thanks for the replies. I ended up clearing the cache. I will have a look at this later.